# Reverse lookup enum in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, colors, enums, google-calendar-api

The function toColor() should resolve number(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color) to color name.

```
Object.prototype.toColor = function() {
    return CalendarApp.EventColor[this];
};

for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++)
sheet.appendRow(events[i].getColor().toColor());
```

I tried the above code, but it says undefined.

Comment: What is your events? Is the function getColor defined for the events?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getcolor